# Does Tomcat support SAML / OKTA?

Tags: tomcat, single-sign-on, okta

We just started using SAP Nakisa. But, it looks like it doesn't support OKTA out of box. 
I am trying to figure out how to at the moment. 
I heard that Nakisa runs on Tomcat. In that case, maybe we can do this with Tomcat directly? Tomcat to OKTA ?

Any advice ?

Comment: Tomcat is a servlet container that Java apps can run on. Do you know if the app (Nakisa?) is built using Java EE (with servlets) or with Spring?

Comment: If you are frontending Tomcat with an HTTP reverse-proxy like Apache http server or Nginx then you could use a SAML SP implementation there. You could also use the Tomcat adapter from Keycloak (https://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.3/securing_apps/topics/saml/java/tomcat-adapter.html)

Comment: new detail question = > [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53124620/oktaidp-shibbolethsp-with-reverse-proxy-to-tomcat)