# OKTA(IdP) - Shibboleth(SP) with reverse proxy to Tomcat

Tags: saml, okta, shibboleth, idp

I am spinning a big wheel now. please shed some light. 
Reverse proxy is working with Apache. So, when I access https://hostname/app/default.html, it opens Tomcat app url. No issue.

The tomcat app currently redirects to https://hostname/app/login.html which has a login box.

1) Do I need to disable UserDatabase on Tomcat server.xml ?

```
<Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
          type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
          description="User database that can be updated and saved"
          factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
          pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
```

2) Is this Shibboleth configuration correct ? 
But, when I try configure this with OKTA- Shibboleth(3.0), it's looping OKTA SSO url.

In shibboleth2.xml

```
<ApplicationDefaults id="default" 
                         entityID="https://hostname/shibboleth-sp" 
                         REMOTE_USER="userid" >
   <SSO entityID="http://www.okta.com/~~~~">
```

OKTA's metadata is downloaded and located with shibboleth2.xml file.
cert is also generated and placed in the same folder.

3) Is this OKTA configuration correct ? 
In OKTA widget configuration menu,

```
- Single sign on url :https://hostname/Shibboleth.sso/SAML2/POST
- recipient url : https://hostname/Shibboleth.sso/SAML2/POST
- destination url :https://hostname/Shibboleth.sso/SAML2/POST
- audience restriction :https://hostname/shibboleth-sp  <-- above SP entityID
- default relay state : ??
```

right now, when I click on the widget on OKTA, it's looping.

```
https://hostname/Shibboleth.sso/SAML2/POST
```

contains SAML response.

then, it redirects to OKTA SSO url. It never ends.

```
https:// xxx.oktapreview.com/app/xx_reverse_proxy_/xxxx/sso/saml?SAMLRequest=~~~&amp;RelayState=~~~
```

This contains SAML request but it looks like this.

```
<samlp:AuthnRequest 
xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" 
AssertionConsumerServiceURL="https://hostname/Shibboleth.sso/SAML2/POST" 
Destination="https://okta sso/sso/saml" 
ID="xx" 
IssueInstant="2018-11-02T15:39:24Z" 
ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" 
Version="2.0">
<saml:Issuer 
    xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">https://hostname/shibboleth-sp
</saml:Issuer>
<samlp:NameIDPolicy 
    AllowCreate="1"/>
```

Is this Issuer url correct? Why is it looping and how to fix ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re Q#1: You only need Tomcat users if you're going to protect an application with it, such as the Tomcat manager. Otherwise, no.

Re Q#2: You list `<SSO entityID="http://www.okta.com/~~~~">` but `Destination="https://okta sso/sso/saml"` from the SAML. You might want to check http/https. This is a very common cause of looping. Eliminate any potential http/https inconsistency.

FWIW Issuer looks correct to me... that's what you specify in `entityID="https://hostname/shibboleth-sp"`

Comment: thanks for answering my questions. I changed <SSO> tag.  <SSO entityID="https://xxx.oktapreview.com/app/xxx/xxxx/sso/saml"
                 discoveryProtocol="SAMLDS" discoveryURL="https://ds.example.org/DS/WAYF">
              SAML2
            </SSO>. Now I don't get looping but it gives me Shibboleth error message like   "Unknown or Unusable Identity Provider / The identity provider supplying your login credentials is not authorized for use with this service or does not support the necessary capabilities/ Identity provider lookup failed at  ~~

Comment: Do i need to change discoveryProtocol / discoveryURL here also?

Comment: If you're not using a discovery service, i.e. you are only using one IdP... then no, you just remove discoveryURL and discoveryProtocol.

Comment: The entityID listed in the SSO tag must be EXPLICITLY what the IdP metadata lists... look at the Okta metadata xml file and make sure you're using exactly what's listed as the entityID on the first line of that file.

Comment: My app on tomcat still has login page. When using SAML, this should be deactivated,correct ? Then, how SAML response can be used to login any user? Does source need to be modified to adapt it?

Comment: Yep... you'll need to parse the server variables. With Tomcat installs, we usually set and AJP connector in Tomcat, and then map the attributes using shibboleth as AJP_attributename, i.e. AJP_uid, or AJP_email. Then you just need to pick those out on your login page. If the login page is protected by Shib, users will be redirected to log in to the IdP, and get pushed back to that page with the attribute info written in the environment variable. Thus, you know if they've come in and the server var is there it's a legit login and you can proceed, knowing whatever attributes you need.

Comment: I have another question .  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54815976/when-using-shibboleth-v3-as-sp-can-i-map-the-attribute-value-in-attribute-ma