# When using Shibboleth (v3) as SP , can I map the attribute value in attribute-map.xml?

Tags: attributes, shibboleth

OKTA is IdP and Shibboleth is SP in this setting. 
OKTA is passing attribute 'roles' something like idp_dev_SLAN_Power, idp_dev_SLAN_Admin, idp_dev_SLAN_account, etc

I am wondering if I can strip 'idp_dev_SLAN_' out when it takes this attribute.

Here is what I see in the current attribute-map.xml.

```
<Attribute id="roles" name="roles" nameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified" />
```

I feel like I can possibly do something with AttributeDecoder. any idea??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are probably looking for the `Transform` type of `AttributeResolver` which:

> applies one or more regular expressions to an input attribute, either replacing its values, or generating new attributes. -- from the [Shibboleth Wiki](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SP3/TransformAttributeResolver)

An example is given:

```
<AttributeResolver type="Transform" source="displayName">
    <Regex match="^(.+) (.+)$" dest="givenName">$1</Regex>
    <Regex match="^(.+) (.+)$" dest="sn">$2</Regex>
    <Regex match="^(.+) (.+)$">$2, $1</Regex>
</AttributeResolver>
```

which transforms a `displayName` into two attributes `givenName` and `sn`. But I'm certain you could build a regular expression to grab `idp_dev_SLAN_` for the various inbound elements and map those to 1 or more attributes of your desire.

Comment: oh. sounds promising. will test out and accept answer soon !! thanks again

Comment: Hi, Kellen . I posted another question .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56045744/how-does-single-logout-works-with-oktaidp-shibbolethsp-app